# Get Request at static ASP.NET Ajax function

Tags: asp.net, ajax, static, request

How can i get the value of:

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

in a static WebMethod function which is used in a ajax-Post? I can't use

```
Environment.UserName
```

because it returns the username of the server at which the web page is running.

I use "Windows Authentication" at the IIS Manager.

Comment: Try using the `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`. Or else you can store in the session. and then use `HttpContext.Current.Session["..."]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` gets you the current ... well, `Http Context`; from which you can access: `Session`, `Request`, `Response` etc.

You can try using the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

Or other way is you can store the value in `session` and then use the

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["logonName"]
```

to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the request in a static method by using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```